Cube faces overlapping issue
I'm pretty new to blender and I have an issue where when two or more cubes overlap one of the faces goes black. I'm using the cycles rendering engine, how should I solve this issue?


Hello, why do you need to make the faces overlap?

@moonboots whenever a cube jumps, I want to duplicate it, so two cubes appear from same place; i could probably move one cube slightly upwards during the animation and it might fix it, but I was curious if there is any setting in blender that could help me

You want the duplicates to be visible 1 frame later, or to start with 0.999 scale

@MarkusvonBroady what if in the scene I have a single cube, no overlaps or any other instance over it and still face this issue, what could be the cause of it?

As you said this is caused by overlapping faces, it is called Z-fighting, you need to avoid that in Cycles, so use the solutions suggested by Markus

@Stefan cycles+instancing+motion blur (+ geonodes?) combo has a bug, so maybe that could be the case for a single object... Or just bad normals or otherwise non-manifold mesh.
